# restrictive or non-restrictive relative pronoun?

Tags: relative-pronouns

I am wondering whether the restrictive relative pronoun **that** or the non-restrictive relative pronoun **which** (plus a comma) should be used to modify the Hunting Lodge in the following:

> Casa Loma consists of three main buildings — the Casa Loma proper, which has a gothic seven-story tower, the two-story Hunting Lodge **that** once housed the home’s servants quarters, and a massive stable.

I'd appreciate your help.

Comment: https://stancarey.wordpress.com/2011/10/18/that-which-is-restrictive/

Comment: It seems "the Hunting Lodge" is standardly capitalized, just like the United States.
If so, is "which" plus a comma a more sensible choice?

Comment: Who fed you the nonsense that "which" is a 'non-restrictive' relative pronoun. It isn't - it's a free choice between "that" and "which" in your example.

Comment: Well, I'm saying "which" is a non-restrictive relative pronoun, but that doesn't mean it cannot be a restrictive relative pronoun. On the other hand, "that" can only be restrictive.

Comment: Note that "which" is preceded by a comma when it serves as a non-restrictive relative pronoun.

Comment: I wouldn't say ***the* Casa Loma proper** but simply **Casa Loma proper**; and **seven-story gothic tower**.